# What's the English word for the care instruction sheet in clothes?

Tags: word-request, translation, image-identification

This sheet with care instructions is attached to any clothes.
What's the name of this sheet?

*My ideas:*

- Washing label
- Care instruction note/sheet
- Washing instruction note/sheet
- Textile care instructions
- Care label

[image: A tag sewn on a cloth item with the washing instructions]

Comment: Any of those. I don't know a favoured term.

Comment: *Label* or *tag* would be more common terms for those.  A *sheet* is something bigger, like a sheet of paper or a bedsheet, and a *note* usually refers to something written casually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK they are properly called *care and content labels*, as they contain not only instructions on washing, but also on handling, drying, and details of the material contained in the product. But you will likely find that people call them by different names. If it isn't something taught in school or something that comes up in everyday conversation then you'll find people tend to just make up their own names for things.